# nautilus-terminal error due to gir1.2-vte-2.90

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, package, nautilus

I like the idea of having a terminal connected to my nautilus file manager.

There is a package called *nautilus-terminal* which does this.

if I try to install it via `sudo apt-get install nautilus-terminal` I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nautilus-terminal : Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.90 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install it via `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-vte-2.90`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gir1.2-vte-2.90 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gir1.2-vte-2.90' has no installation candidate
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because you already have `gir1.2-vte-2.91` installed on your ubuntu but since the package name contains version number, it's not recognized as a higher version of `gir1.2-vte-2.90` so you just need to provide a package with the name `gir1.2-vte-2.90` and connect it to `gir1.2-vte-2.91`. This can be easily done by following the instructions of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/819056/656685).